Reduced mass in a Harmonic Oscillator
I recently came across the harmonic oscillator and the concept of reduced mass, i.e
$$
\mu = \frac{m_1m_2}{m_1 + m_2} 
$$
To begin, I understand the derivation from the point of view of sitting on one mass/from the C.O.M frame. I have been however using the following method for doing problems, it is simpler and uses the concept of potentials from conservative forces. Say, we want to find $\omega$ for a case of single-body oscillations. Then
$$
\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2 =\text{const} 
$$
For any particle in S.H.M. So,
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2)=0, \\ 
& mv\frac{dv}{dt} + kx\frac{dx}{dt}=0, \\ 
&ma =-kx , (\because \frac{dx}{dt}=v), \\ 
&\omega= \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}
\end{align*} 
$$
Easy enough. However, for the two body problem, I dont seem to be getting the correct equation using this approach. Would it be possible to proceed with this approach and if so then how would that look like? Till now, I have been able to do the following.
Say the two masses are $m_1$ and $m_2$ with velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively at any general time $t$. Also, at this instant say the elongation of the spring be $x$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx^2= \text{const} \\ 
&\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx^2) =0 \\ 
& m_1v_1\frac{dv_1}{dt} + m_2v_2\frac{dv_2}{dt}+ kx\frac{dx}{dt}=0\\ 
& m_1v_1\frac{dv_1}{dt} + m_2v_2\frac{dv_2}{dt}+ kx(v_2-v_1)=0\\
\end{align*}
$$
I do not know how to proceed with further solution development. Could we perhaps use momentum conservation of a system comprising of $m_1$ and $m_2$ to find a relation between the velocities?

You must have two coordinates to describe the motion.
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}k(x_2-x_1)^2= \text{const} \\ 
&\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 + \frac{1}{2}k(x_2-x_1)^2) =0 \\ 
& m_1v_1\frac{dv_1}{dt} + m_2v_2\frac{dv_2}{dt}+ k(x_2-x_1)\frac{dx{_2}}{dt} -k(x_2-x_1)\frac{dx{_1}}{dt}=0\\ 
& m_1a_1=k(x_2-x_1) \\
& m_2a_2=-k(x_2-x_1)\\
\end{align*}
This solves

dammit. Thankyou so much.
